# Plotting BQML boosted tree regressor using XGBoost plot_tree

Tags: python, google-bigquery, xgboost

I trained a boosted tree regressor in BQML, and exported the model. See below the resulting file structure.
[image]

I'm able to import the model.bst file with XBoost and plot the decision tree, but the name of the features are missing from the plot.

```
    # plot decision tree
    from xgboost import XGBRegressor, plot_tree, plot_importance
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    %matplotlib inline
    
    plt.style.use('ggplot')
    
    model=XGBRegressor()
    model.load_model('./boostedtree_model/model.bst')
    
    plt.figure(figsize=(50,50))  # set plot size (denoted in inches)
    
    plot_tree(model,fontsize="48",rankdir='LR')
    plt.savefig('boosted_tree.pdf',bbox_inches='tight',dpi=1200)
```

For what I could find on the internet, BQML do not generate a model.json, which would contain the model and the feature names.

Does anyone knows how to get the names for BQML trained models?

Comment: I tried this [bq example](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/export-model-tutorial#train_and_deploy_a_boosted_tree_classifier_model) to train a boosted tree model. I found the `feature_names` in `assets/model_metadata.json` which exists on your screenshot and your model name should be the folder name. Just to confirm, are these the information that you are looking for?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. I'm looking for a feature_names file.